# Insert records from multiple rows of table to multiple columns of other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing table structure with sample data like

| Id | BookingId | Value | TypeId | AddedTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10 | T1 | 2021-03-22 08:51:52.6333333 |
| 2 | 100 | 20 | T2 | 2021-03-22 08:50:55.8133333 |
| 3 | 100 | 30 | T3 | 2021-03-22 08:50:22.1033333 |
| 4 | 200 | 50 | T1 | 2021-03-22 08:50:22.1033333 |
| 5 | 200 | 60 | T2 | 2021-03-22 08:50:22.1000000 |
| 6 | 200 | 70 | T3 | 2021-03-22 08:50:22.0800000 |

and now data model is changed and it becomes like

| Id | BookingId | Type1Value | Type2Value | Type3Value | AddedTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Please help me what would be query to copy data from previous table to new table.

Output should be something like

| Id | BookingId | Type1Value | Type2Value | Type3Value | AddedTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 10 | 20 | 30 |  |
| 2 | 200 | 50 | 60 | 70 |  |

I tried:

```
select BookingId
    , Type1Value = max(case when RN=1 then Value else null end)
    , Type2Value = max(case when RN=2 then Value else null end)
    , Type3Value = max(case when RN=3 then Value else null end)
from (
    select *
        , rn = Row_Number() over (Partition By TypeId Order by AddedTime) 
    from Values_M
) a
where rn <= 3
group by BookingId
```

Comment: Please show us the query you wrote using pivot and stuff. And clarify, are there always 3 rows to combine or might there sometimes be only 1 or 2? And what should be displayed for AddedTime?

Comment: **Don't do it**. The original table design is fine.

Comment: Actually from UI all 3 records will post in one go, so AddedTime for migrated records may be the first AddedTime of each group.
Secondly always there will be 3 rows to be combined

Comment: I tried yesterday with pivot and some way of union and group by but didn't get expected result

Comment: @Squirrel's suggestion is valid.  What is driving the structural change to this table?  It would generally be advisable to keep the structure that you have, rather than flattening based on "today's" structure ...... you can almost guarantee that Type4, Type5, Type6 values will come along at some point in the future - then the table structure will need to keep changing each time a functional change occurs.  Not ideal

Comment: @Squirrel, no doubt original design of table is correct, but in system it's well defined (as per requirement) that TypeIds will not increase in future, so the new structure of table is defined,
Please help me what would be query to migrate (copy ) records from old table structure to new table structure

Comment: @DaleK, since i didn't get expected result from my efforts so i deleted everything.
can you please suggest some way to write query for above requirement, i will write new query and show to you.

Comment: @DaleK I tried this

select BookingId
       ,Type1Value = max(case when RN=1 then Value else null end)
       ,Type2Value = max(case when RN=2 then Value else null end)
       ,Type3Value = max(case when RN=3 then Value else null end)
      
 from  (
         Select *,rn = Row_Number() over (Partition By TypeId Order by AddedTime)
         From  Values_M
       ) a
 where rn<=3
 Group By BookingId

it gives result

 100  null   30    null
 200  70    null   null

Comment: What if you keep the current table design and create a view to return the data in the required format ?

Comment: @user4365176 please update your question with additional information.

Comment: @Squirrel we are using EF core code first approach, and we want to copy data from old table to new table before dropping old table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will gives you the required result using conditional case expression.

Using `row_number()` to generate new running number `Id`

```
select Id         = row_number() over (order by BookingId),
       BookingId  = BookingId,
       Type1Value = max(case when TypeId = 'T1' then Value end),
       Type2Value = max(case when TypeId = 'T2' then Value end),
       Type3Value = max(case when TypeId = 'T3' then Value end),   
       AddedTime  = min(AddedTime)
from   Values_M
group by BookingId
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1704f13b328d6183f1b08ef04ad6518f)

Comment: thanks @Squirrel, this gives expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select BookingId, min(T1) as Type1Value, min(T2) as Type2Value, min(T3) as Type3Value
from table1
pivot (sum(value) for Typeid in (T1,T2,T3)) as PivotTable
group by BookingId
```

Comment: A little explanation is always nice, instead of code only answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and self join.

```
with cte as (
    select Id, BookingId, [Value], TypeId, AddedTime
        , row_number() over (partition by BookingId order by id asc) rn
    from Values_M
)
select C1.rn, C1.BookingId, C1.[Value] Type1Value, C2.[Value] Type2Value, C3.[Value] Type3Value, C1.AddedTime
from cte C1
inner join cte C2 on C2.BookingId = C1.BookingId and C2.rn = 2
inner join cte C3 on C3.BookingId = C1.BookingId and C3.rn = 3
where C1.rn = 1
order by BookingId asc;
```

Comment: Thanks @DaleK this gives too expected result